# cellUpdate from jqgrid custom formatter

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I'm using jqgrid and am trying to request data from a webservice, parse it, and update a grid cell with the value.  I expected to be able to do this with a custom formatter but I haven't been able to connect the dots on the asynchronous part of this function.

I've also ready that it may be wiser to use the gridLoaded { } call for this type of feature but in my mind the code I have below should work...

The formatter function gets called, make the async query which when completed fires the callback function which in turn updates the grid cell.

Any suggestions on what I may be missing would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

```
function recentPostsFormatter(cellValue, options, jsonVal) {

var encodedUrl = jsonVal.urlId;   
var globalHTML = "";
var wsquery = 'webservice query goes here';


$.getJSON(wsquery, function (result) {
    var html = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < result.response.docs.length; i++) {
        html += "<b>" + result.response.docs[i].title + "</b><br>" + result.response.docs[i].blogLink + ", " + result.response.docs[i].author + "<br>";

    }

$("#blogListTable").jqGrid('setCell', object.rowId, 'recentPosts', html);           

});



}
```

Comment: whats your question? is this working for you?

Comment: No this doesn't work, I've debugged it further and there are a couple bugs in the above code but I believe you can't execute the setCell command in the formatter because the cell hasn't been created yet.

Comment: So really I am looking for tips on how to fire off a request for ws data when a row is being loaded, and then update ea. row when that async request compeltes.